# Working with multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a class that works width matrices. In its constructor it wants to know the height and width of the array and it wants the array itself and then it has to be able to print the array and overload some operators. The Array must be an array of floats. This is what I have so far:
Two defined parameters:

```
#define HEIGHT 3
#define WIDTH 3
```

Making the array:

```
void Assignment_1::start(){
    float **matrix = new float *[HEIGHT];
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
        matrix[i] = new float[WIDTH];
    }
    //  5   6   11
    //  7   2   8
    //  5   1   4
    matrix[0][0]=5;
    matrix[0][1]=6;
    matrix[0][2]=11;
    matrix[1][0]=7;
    matrix[1][1]=2;
    matrix[1][2]=8;
    matrix[2][0]=5;
    matrix[2][1]=1;
    matrix[2][2]=4;
    Matrix * matrixA = new Matrix(HEIGHT,WIDTH,matrix);
    matrixA->printMatrix();
}
```

Right now I understand that a C++ two-dimensional array exists of a normal array of HEIGHT pointers, each of which point to an array of WIDTH size.

The constructor and the global vars:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int width, int height, float **array){
    this->height = height;
    this->width = width;
    this->array = array;
}
//in Matrix.h:
int width, height;
float ** array;
```

Until this point everything is fine. Now I want to actually use the array by printing it:

```
void Matrix::printMatrix(){
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++){
        for (int w = 0; w < width;w++){
            std::cout <<array[height][width]<<"    ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And this is where it goes wrong: the program simply crashes. I kinda get why it crashes: I think I need to get what array[h] is pointing to (which is a float array of size width), but trying to do that gives me the error: cannot convert float* to float[]*. What do I need to do?

Comment: array[height][width] -> array[h][w]. Also, std::vector. Also, boost.multiarray. Also https://gist.github.com/rmartinho/3959961

Comment: Oh. Typing error. After I fully understand multi-dimensional array's I will look into vectors, but Im still learning, so I dont want to rush to templates until I know the basics.

Comment: std::vector *is* the basics. Manual memory management is the advanced stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The robot already answered your question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065858/cworking-width-multi-dimensional-arrays#comment21184463_15065858)

```
for (int h = 0; h < height; h++){
    for (int w = 0; w < width;w++){
        std::cout <<array[height][width]<<"    ";
                  //      ^^^^^^  ^^^^^
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

What entries are you accessing? Well, always `array[height][width]`. However, `array` contains only `height` elements, so this access results in undefined behaviour. Simply apply your loop variables `h` and `w`:

```
for (int h = 0; h < height; h++){
    for (int w = 0; w < width;w++){
        std::cout << array[h][w]<<"    ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But still, this is far from optimal. You should use a type which is easier to use, for example `std::vector`:

```
typedef std::vector<float> float_vector;
typedef std::vector<float_vector> float_matrix;
float_matrix matrix(HEIGHT,float_vector(WIDTH));
```

`std::vector` is one of the most important types. Master it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because 2 dimensional array and pointer to pointer are not same. Can you try

float **array to float (*array)[size]?

and change array[height][width] to array[h][w]

Answer (score 1):

```
void Matrix::printMatrix(){
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++){
        for (int w = 0; w < width;w++){
            std::cout <<array[h][w]<<"    ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

not height and width - it is size of you array, use you iterators h,w